# How do I reinstall ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: 20.04, video, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I cannot play any downloaded videos(mp3/mkv). I already ran `sudo apt autoremove ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras` several times but the EULA pop-up never opens. What else can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "EULA pop-up never opens". Post output of the install command to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am expecting this prompt: https://linux-tips.us/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/Selection_237.png but it never appears. I get no error on installation. However, I get no video or sound when I try to play a video on VLC.